# Change component in the editor tab in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, editor, intellij-plugin

I have some plugin project which demands custom editor tab. However I can't find out the way to change text editor component to my custom component. Is there any way I can change it or should I only create my custom editor tab?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement the `FileEditorProvider` interface. In the `getPolicy()` method, you can return `FileEditorPolicy#HIDE_DEFAULT_EDITOR`, in which case your file editor will be used instead of the standard file editor for that file.

Comment: So the only way is to create my custom editor? I'm quite lost in creating my own editor. Didn't find any understandable articles about that.

Comment: What's the difficult part? You get a VirtualFile and you need to return a Swing component that represents the editor. Pretty much everything else is optional.